# Issue With JavaScript / HTML Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html

The method validateRegistrationForm is not being called, I have tested this by placing an alert inside and can't figure out why this is the case.

There is other JavaScript to validate other things though I have removed that until this issue is resolved.

The JavaScript itself is being linked to the HTML via script tags inside of the body. I put an alert at the top of the JS to make sure the link is working and it is.

HTML:

```
<form name="registrationForm" id="registrationForm" action="AddUserDetails">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <span id="firstNameError">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Second Name</label>
        <span id="lastNameError">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        <span id="phoneNumberError">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eMail">E-Mail</label>
        <span id="eMailError">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eMail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eMailConfirmation">Confirm E-Mail</label>
        <span id="eMailConfirmationError">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eMailConfirmation">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <span id="passwordError">*</span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
    </div>
</form>

<div class="text-center">
    <input type="button" id="submitRegistationForm" value="Submit">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var validateRegistrationForm = function () {
    alert("");
    var isValid = true;

    //First Name Validation
    if ($("firstName").value == "") {
        $("firstNameError").firstChild.nodeValue = "This Text Box Cannot Be Blank";
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        $("firstNameError").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
    }

    //Second Name Validation
    if ($("lastName").value == "") {
        $("lastNameError").firstChild.nodeValue = "This Text Box Cannot Be Blank";
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        $("lastNameError").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
    }

    if (isValid) {
        $("registrationForm").submit();
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    $("submitRegistationForm").onclick = validateRegistrationForm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redefining $ seems like an awful idea, especially if this is code shared amongst other developers. In either case, why even wait for window.onload? You could just declare your click handler outside of it. Working jsfiddle:

```
$("submitRegistationForm").onclick = validateRegistrationForm;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ou3gLLqe/